# Error Downloading from Database to Excel File using PHP Spreadsheet

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to create a page that can download hundred thousand data and export it in to excel file using PHPSpreadSheet how ever I'm getting HTTP ERROR 500

```
include('../config.php');

require_once '../../epson/resources/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$filename = generateFileName($filename);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

  $activeSheet->setCellValue('A1', 'pcbid');
  $activeSheet->setCellValue('B1', 'pcbtype');
  $activeSheet->setCellValue('C1', 'grouprev');
  $activeSheet->setCellValue('D1', 'symbol');

  $mdthistorydownloadresult = $conn->query($sql);
  if($mdthistorydownloadresult->num_rows > 0) {
      $i = 2;
      while($row = $mdthistorydownloadresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('A'. $i, $row['pcbid']);
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('B'. $i, $row['pcbtype']);
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('C'. $i, $row['grouprev']);
        $activeSheet->setCellValue('D'. $i, $row['symbol']);
          $i++;
      }
  }
  $Excel_writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='. $filename .'.xlsx');
  $Excel_writer->save('php://output');

exit;
```

total rows = 136750

It is perfectly working when I limit the query to 1000.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: there are several reasons posible ... PHP timeout: The script takes to long or PHP memory limit: A process exceeds memory and therefore cannot be executed correctly try increasing the `memory_limit`

Comment: post the mysql code. but I do not believe that a select query on 200.000 entries ecxceeds 0.5 sec